# How do I get south to work on jython2.7-django1.7?

Tags: django, postgresql, jython, django-south

I hoping that you can help me out.  I currently have Django1.7 running on windows7/Java7/Jython2.7/Postgresql9.3/postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.

For more details about django on jython and the database settings.
[postgresql on jython-django](https://pythonhosted.org/django-jython/database-backends.html#postgresql)

My settings are:

```
DATABASES = {
     'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'doj.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'lwc',
        'USER': 'lwc',
        'PASSWORD': 'lwc',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

My Question:
I am not able to install South by using pip.  So, I just installed it manually from the source.  Afterwards I do jython manage.py syncdb

I then get an error... Do you have any ideas how to resolve this error?

```
C:\Users\michmar3\workspace\lwc>jython manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\core\mana
gement\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\core\mana
gement\__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\__init__.
py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\apps\regi
stry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\apps\conf
ig.py", line 197, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\south-1.0-py2.7.egg\south\models.py", l
ine 2, in <module>
    from south.db import DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\south-1.0-py2.7.egg\south\db\__init__.p
y", line 84, in <module>
    db = dbs[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
KeyError: 'default'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`south` will not work with `django` 1.7.  http://south.aeracode.org/

The functionality that `south` used to provide has been directly merged into django with the 1.7 release.

See the `django` documentation for how to use the `django` migration support that replaces `south`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/

Comment: If you are getting an error related to using `django` 1.7 built in migrations, you should ask it in a new question so other people can look it up when they get the same error.

Comment: Here is the new question:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25716496/why-am-i-getting-an-error-when-i-run-the-migrate-command-on-jython-django-1-7-h

Comment: seems like migrations isn't working properly in Django 1.7.  It is failing when I add a new column and try to default the value to "ABC". It looks like it is attempting to perform the wrong database calls.