# Why am I getting an error when I run the migrate command on Jython-Django 1.7? How do I resolve it?

Tags: django, postgresql, migration, jython

I hoping that you can help me out.  I currently have Django1.7 running on windows7/Java7/Jython2.7/Postgresql9.3/postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.

I learned today that on Django 1.7 there is no reason to install the South package for migrations because 1.7 has makemigrations and migrate commands built in.  But even so when I try to apply those commands in that order I am getting some sort of error.  How can I resolve this error?

For more information on django migrations.
[Django 1.7 Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/)

For more details about django on jython and the database settings.
[postgresql on jython-django](https://pythonhosted.org/django-jython/database-backends.html#postgresql)

My settings are:

```
DATABASES = {
     'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'doj.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'lwc',
        'USER': 'lwc',
        'PASSWORD': 'lwc',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

This is my models.py file and I am trying to add ip_address when I do the makemigrations and migrate commands.

```
from django.db import models

class Join(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True) #This is the new field
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" %(self.email)
```

Here is the error that I get from running the migrate command:

```
C:\Users\mike\workspace\lwc>jython manage.py migrate
←[36;1mOperations to perform:←[0m
←[1m  Apply all migrations: ←[0madmin, sessions, joins, auth, contenttypes
←[36;1mRunning migrations:←[0m
  Applying joins.0003_join_ip_address...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\core\mana
gement\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\core\mana
gement\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\core\mana
gement\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\core\mana
gement\base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\core\mana
gement\commands\migrate.py", line 160, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\db\migrat
ions\executor.py", line 63, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\db\migrat
ions\executor.py", line 97, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\db\migrat
ions\migration.py", line 107, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, ne
w_state)
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\db\migrat
ions\operations\fields.py", line 35, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\db\backen
ds\schema.py", line 411, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\db\backen
ds\schema.py", line 98, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\db\backen
ds\utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\db\backen
ds\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\db\utils.
py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django-1.7c3-py2.7.egg\django\db\backen
ds\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django_jython-1.7.0b2-py2.7.egg\doj\db\
backends\__init__.py", line 180, in execute
    self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.Error: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1 [SQL
Code: 0], [SQLState: 42P18]
```

I ran sqlmigrate because I understand that this is the sql calls that it is suppose to attempt to run.  And I am not a DBA, but they don't look right to me.  Anybody out there know SQL for Postgresql really well?

```
C:\Users\mike\workspace\lwc>jython manage.py sqlmigrate joins 0002_join_ref_
id
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE `joins_join` ADD COLUMN `ref_id` varchar(120) DEFAULT "ABC" NOT NULL
;
ALTER TABLE `joins_join` ALTER COLUMN `ref_id` DROP DEFAULT;

COMMIT;
```

I tried running that command in the Postgresql Query tool and I got the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "ABC" does not exist
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "ABC" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
```

So, then this looks like a bug with Django 1.7.  Has anyone else had this issue?  What is the correct SQL statement?  How could I create a workaround or resolve this issue?

Comment: Maybe I am not suppose to use Default= "ABC" with migrations with postgresql?

Comment: "PostgreSQL is the most capable of all the databases here in terms of schema support; the only caveat is that adding columns with default values will cause a full rewrite of the table, for a time proportional to its size.

For this reason, it’s recommended you always create new columns with null=True, as this way they will be added immediately.

Comment: I just tried the following steps with mysql and the mysql jdbc and I get the same error.  So, it looks like there is an issue with the Django migrations code when trying to apply the sql call.

C:\Users\mike\workspace\lwc>jython manage.py sqlmigrate joins 0002_join_ref_
id
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE `joins_join` ADD COLUMN `ref_id` varchar(120) DEFAULT "ABC" NOT NULL
;
ALTER TABLE `joins_join` ALTER COLUMN `ref_id` DROP DEFAULT;

COMMIT;